# Parallel processes: appending outputs to an array in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, parallel-processing

I have a for loop in which a function `task` is called. Each call to the function returns a string that is appended to an array. I would like to parallelise this for loop. I tried using `&` but it does not seem to work.

Here is the code not parallelised.

```
task (){ sleep 1;echo "hello $1"; }
arr=()

for i in {1..3}; do
    arr+=("$(task $i)")
done

for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
    echo "$i x";
done
```

The output is:

```
hello 1 x
hello 2 x
hello 3 x
```

Great! But now, when I try to parallelise it with

```
[...]
for i in {1..3}; do
    arr+=("$(task $i)")&
done
wait
[...]
```

the output is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**GNU Parallel** is good at doing stuff in parallel :-)

```
task (){ sleep 1;echo "hello $1"; }

# Make "task" known to sub shells
export -f task

# Do tasks in parallel
parallel -k task ::: {1..3}
```

**Sample Output**

```
hello 1
hello 2
hello 3
```

I am suggesting you do - but Charles kindly points out that this is a known `bash` pitfall:

```
array=( $(parallel -k task ::: {1..3}) )
```

Charles' suggested solution is:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a array < <(parallel -k task ::: 1 2 3 && printf '\0')
```

Comment: Executing you code yields `zsh:1: command not found: task`. Is it a `zsh`-specific issue?

Comment: @BiBi, you tagged this with `bash`, not `zsh`. Please use correct tags for your setup.

Comment: Just added the `zsh` tag. I'm also interested in bash, I'm going to try your solution with bash.

Comment: `export -f` is a bash-ism that makes functions visible to sub-shells

Comment: I can't speak for zsh, but `array=( $( ... ) )` is an antipattern in bash; see [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29). `read -ra array < <(...)` is less error-prone, as is `readarray -t array < <(...)`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for the hint. Sadly, I can't make it work like that (my `bash` is likely too old) so I'll delete the answer shortly.

Comment: Hmm. `readarray -t` was added in bash 4.0, but `read -ra` should work in 3.x.

Comment: Oh -- if it's line-oriented input, make it `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a array < <(... && printf '\0')`; that actually has a benefit over other forms, *including* `readarray`, insofar as it exits with a nonzero exit status if the `...` does.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Your answers works great. That being said, since there is a space in the output of `task`, the array sees it as two elements instead of 1.

Comment: @BiBi, ...that'll be solved with the `IFS=$'\n'`. That said, note that the current answer will change a line containing only `*` in the output to a list of filenames.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I cannot seem to make your correction work. What exactly should I put in between the parenthesis?

Comment: `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a array < <(parallel -k task ::: 1 2 3 && printf '\0')` -- note that I stopped using `{1..3}` because of some bugs in how old versions of bash handle it. `values=( {1..3} )` and then `parallel -k task ::: "${values[@]}"` sidestep those issues.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy works like a charm! Thanks to both of you! Now, I'm looking for a zsh equivalent :).

Comment: @MarkSetchell Have a look at `parset`.

Answer (score 0):

Try encapsulating your adding step into a function or a temporary script, but send the items to a file instead. I think you will need some command that I can't remember on top of my head for dealing with file lock. See if you need to export things too. Then you source the file at the end. Something like:

```
echo 'arr=(' > temp
add() { echo item >> temp; }
...
export -f add
...
add &
...
echo ')' > temp
source temp
rm temp
```

Comment: You're going to need to fill in the `...`s more to have a correct solution -- at minimum, for example, you'll need to wait for all the subprocesses to finish. And you'll need to be more careful to not accidentally truncate the file. (Though one thing you *don't* need to worry about here is file locking, so long as each thread ends in a single write of less-than-a-page length with the `O_APPEND` flag set).

Comment: I would strongly suggest having successfully tested an answer at least once (copied-and-pasted, not manually entered with human-length delays between commands) before calling it complete.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `parset` (part of GNU Parallel since 20170422) or `env_parset` (available since 20171222):

```
# If you have not run:
#    env_parallel --install
# and logged in again, then you can instead run this to activate (env_)parset:
. `which env_parallel.bash`

task (){
  echo "hello $1"
  sleep 1.$1
  perl -e 'print "binary\001\002\n"'
  sleep 1.$1
  echo output of parallel jobs do not mix
}
env_parset arr task ::: {1..3}
env_parset a,b,c task ::: {1..3}

echo "${arr[1]}" | xxd
echo "$b" | xxd
```

`parset` is supported in Bash/Ksh/Zsh (including arrays), ash/dash (without arrays).

Answer (score -2):

Try encapsulating your adding step into a function or a temporary script. See if you need to export things too. Something like:

```
add() { arr+=(value); }
...
export -f add
...
add &
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because background tasks are run in a subprocess; they can't impact the variables that are active in the parent-process shell.