# Parallel processes: appending outputs to an array in a zsh script

Tags: linux, shell, parallel-processing, zsh

I have a for loop in which a function `task` is called. Each call to the function returns a string that is appended to an array. I would like to parallelise this for loop. I tried using `&` but it does not seem to work.

Here is the code not parallelised.

```
task (){ sleep 1;echo "hello $1"; }
arr=()

for i in {1..3}; do
    arr+=("$(task $i)")
done

for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
    echo "$i x";
done
```

The output is:

```
hello 1 x
hello 2 x
hello 3 x
```

Great! But now, when I try to parallelise it with

```
[...]
for i in {1..3}; do
    arr+=("$(task $i)")&
done
wait
[...]
```

the output is empty.

This question is specifically for `zsh`, for its `bash` counterpart please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51544071/parallel-processes-appending-outputs-to-an-array-in-a-bash-script).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parallel processes: appending outputs to an array in a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51544071/parallel-processes-appending-outputs-to-an-array-in-a-bash-script)

Comment: It’s not a duplicate: this question is about zsh in particular, the other one about bash.

Comment: use GNU Parallel -- as answered in your other question.

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure you *don't* want to do quite that.

I'll leave the original solution below, but try it with a coproc.

```
#! /usr/bin/zsh

coproc cat &

task(){
  sleep $1
  print -p "Sloppy simulation process # $1: $(date)"
}

arr=()

for i in {1..3}; do
    task $i &
done

for i in {1..3}; do
    read -p val
    arr+=("$val")
done

for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
    [[ -n "$i" ]] && echo "$i"
done
```

Ideally, the writes to the coproc will take long enough that the reads will start first and block.

I think.

My output:

```
Sloppy simulation process # 1: Thu Jul 26 15:19:02 CDT 2018
Sloppy simulation process # 2: Thu Jul 26 15:19:03 CDT 2018
Sloppy simulation process # 3: Thu Jul 26 15:19:04 CDT 2018
```

---

> original file storing version

---

If `task` is a long-running step, it might be worth paralleling the work and adding the overhead of storing it somewhere persistent and then loading the array. Is this quick hack out helpful?

```
task(){ # task() handles persistence itself
  sleep $1
  echo "Sloppy simulation process # $1: $(date)" >| /tmp/task/$1
}

mkdir -p /tmp/task/
cd /tmp/task 

for i in {1..3}
do  task $i & # run them in background
done
wait          # wait for the last one

arr=()
for f in *
do  arr[$f]="$(<$f)" # read each into arr
done

for i in $( seq ${#arr[@]} )
do [[ -n "${arr[$i]}" ]] && echo "${arr[$i]}" # show them
done

rm -fr /tmp/task/
```

Comment: Your solution will work, but I'm rather looking for a solution that does not require writing outputs to file. You can see `task` as a function taking 10 seconds to run and you'd rather not adding this overhead. Thanks for the solution anyway!

Comment: This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51544158/6246880) works like a charm but only in bash (because `export -f` does not work in zsh).

Comment: I figured, but assignment in background means in a subshell, yes? Won't work. You have to have some form of persistence to move the result back up to the parent.

 Maybe a coprocess or named pipe as a queue?

Comment: @BiBi, ...one could make it work without `export -f` in bash by using `declare -f` to print a declaration of your function and substitute that into the code run in the subprocess. Maybe that'll work in zsh?

Comment: @PaulHodges, ...btw, again, I don't know zsh, but at least *in bash* the `for i in $(seq ...)` is a significant amount of performance overhead (forking off a subprocess and running an external command within it), compared to `for i in "${!arr[@]}"; do` which is purely shell-builtin.

Comment: Thanks - couldn't quite remember the ideal method and didn't want to skip tracks to go look it up, lol. Will edit it in for posterity. ;)

Comment: Researching and upgrading that found several other problems. I still had an `-e` in the `read -ep` so it wasn't loading the array at all, was just sending to stdout. Fixed that. Then the ! in "${!arr[@]}" wasn't parsing. Works when I remove it. hm... Actually kinda surprised that it's working with the space-embedded items but not the indices. Maybe a zsh thing. *Caveat Scriptor.*

Answer (score 1):

zsh comes with [zargs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zargs). It would be handy in order to do some xargs-ish parallel operations on shell functions.

```
task () {
  sleep $1
  echo "hello $1"
}
arr=()

autoload -Uz zargs

arr=("${(@f)"$(zargs -P 3 -n 1 -- {3..1} -- task)"}")

print -l ${(qqq)arr}
#>> "hello 1"
#>> "hello 2"
#>> "hello 3"
```

---

Here is `zargs --help` output:

```
Usage: zargs [options --] [input-args] [-- command [initial-args]]

If command and initial-args are omitted, "print -r --" is used.

Options:
--eof[=eof-str], -e[eof-str]
    Change the end-of-input-args string from "--" to eof-str.  If
    given as --eof=, an empty argument is the end; as --eof or -e,
    with no (or an empty) eof-str, all arguments are input-args.
--exit, -x
    Exit if the size (see --max-chars) is exceeded.
--help
    Print this summary and exit.
--interactive, -p
    Prompt before executing each command line.
--max-args=max-args, -n max-args
    Use at most max-args arguments per command line.
--max-chars=max-chars, -s max-chars
    Use at most max-chars characters per command line.
--max-lines[=max-lines], -l[max-lines]
    Use at most max-lines of the input-args per command line.
    This option is misnamed for xargs compatibility.
--max-procs=max-procs, -P max-procs
    Run up to max-procs command lines in the background at once.
--no-run-if-empty, -r
    Do nothing if there are no input arguments before the eof-str.
--null, -0
    Split each input-arg at null bytes, for xargs compatibility.
--replace[=replace-str], -i[replace-str]
    Substitute replace-str in the initial-args by each initial-arg.
    Implies --exit --max-lines=1.
--verbose, -t
    Print each command line to stderr before executing it.
--version
    Print the version number of zargs and exit.
```

It uses `--max-procs=max-procs, -P max-procs` and `--max-args=max-args, -n max-args` on above example.